# Rails validate type date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I think i might be dreaming, but i think i read somewhere that you can validate the type of an attribute of an object before you save it? Something
like `validates :transaction_date, :type => Date` and that will make sure that its a date?

Is this possible in Rails 3.2? i am trying to find evidence of this on the net. i have already looked here at the [rails api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) and i am going through the  [ActiveRecord support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).

Comment: Yes http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails doesn't support this directly; the closest it comes is probably validates_format_of, or supplying your own custom validator.

I think what you want is the [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) gem. It not only validates that something is a valid date, but you can specify whether it should be before or after today and various other date range checks.

Comment: We use validates_timeliness and it works very well for our purposes. +1

Answer (score 19):

As a complement to the other answers, note that you can define a custom validator to let you use exactly the syntax you proposed:

```
validates :transaction_date, :type => Date
```

as follows:

```
class TypeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "is not of class #{options[:with]}") unless
      value.class == options[:with]
  end
end
```

Of course, if you want to allow subclasses, you could change the test to use `kind_of?`.

Comment: Very clean, should be in Rails by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following gem:

https://github.com/codegram/date_validator

It contains a date validator. You can add a few options.

Answer (score 1):

A new gem has been created to help [validate types in rails](https://github.com/yez/validates_type) and an [explanatory blog post](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/05/10/validates-type/) exists to answer more of the "why" it was created in the first place.

With this library your code would simple be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_type :transaction_date, :date
end
```

This will throw an exception when anything except a a `Date` is assigned to `:transaction_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another custom validator that uses `is_a?` instead of `class`, and therefore is a bit less strict and handles things such as `Numeric`:

```
class IsAValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "is not a #{options[:with]}") unless
      value.is_a?(options[:with])
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
validates :number, is_a: Numeric
```