# Validate a string in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, validation

How can I validate if something is a string? Is it something along the lines of:

```
validates :title, format: string
```

Comment: I would write a custom validator like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831869/rails-validate-type-date

Comment: Hmmm, I was using validates :year, numericality: true in order to validate that year is a number. Is there nothing of that sort for strings? @cwitty

Comment: Unfortunately no. Validating that something is numerical is more common. If you validate something is a string you normally care about its format. You could use the validates_format_of method and specify the regex you want to accept. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered that in order to validate that the data I am inputting contains only letters (I guess a string in this instance), I can use the following code, which validates that the format of the title is all letters, using Regex (the stuff between the //).

```
validates :title, format: {with: /[a-zA-Z]/}
```